# JavaScript: Can't dynamically reset checkbox values for dynamically created checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I dynamically created a set of checkboxes and labels in plain JavaScript. This works fine and the checkboxes are displayed:

```
const label = document.createElement("label");
const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
const description = document.createTextNode(course[i].name);

checkbox.type = "checkbox";
checkbox.id = "checkbox-" + course[i].name;
checkbox.value = course[i].name;

label.appendChild(checkbox);
label.appendChild(description);

const mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
mainDiv.appendChild(label);
```

However, when I click a button elsewhere on the screen, I need that eventHandler to reset all of the checkbox values so that they are all unchecked. I tried both of the following two options. None give me browser errors, but neither have the desired effect:

```
for (let i = 0, l = allItems.length; i < l; ++i) {
    document.getElementById("checkbox-" + allItems[i].name).checked = false;
 }

$("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
this.checked = false;
});
```

Inside the browser console I can retrieve the value of "checked", and set it to false, but the UI does not reflect this change. I looked all over on StackOverflow. Although there were people within similar questions, I could not get the suggested solutions to work for me.

[image: Browser debugging results]

Comment: `inspect` and check the Id of checkbox's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to uncheck the check boxes inside the button's event handler function:

```
$('#reset').click(function(){
 $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
   this.checked = false;
 });
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var course = [{name: 'TestCourse1'},{name: 'TestCourse2'},{name: 'TestCourse3'}]
for(var i = 0; i < course.length; i++){
  const label = document.createElement("label");
  const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
  const description = document.createTextNode(course[i].name);

  checkbox.type = "checkbox";
  checkbox.id = "checkbox-" + course[i].name;
  checkbox.value = course[i].name;

  label.appendChild(checkbox);
  label.appendChild(description);

  const mainDiv = document.getElementById("main");
  mainDiv.appendChild(label);
}

$('#reset').click(function(){
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
    this.checked = false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>

<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, Giulio. I tested your code and it first it did not work. I forgot to mention that I am using jQueryUI for the checkbox styling. I turned this off and the checkboxes worked as expected. I will need to look into the jQueryUI issue then, but at least I know now that I can get the plain checkbox option to work.